# Referencing an item within an algorithm box

Tags: enumerate, labels, algorithms, ref

At the moment I am using a reference to an enumeration within an algorithm box. However, the reference only shows the number of the enumeration but nothing of the algorithm. How can I put the number of the algorithm in front of the item number of the enumeration? Is it possible to override `\ref` with an if condition to check if it is inside of an algorithm box?

```
\begin{algorithm}[h!]
 \caption{Random Forest}\label{alg}
 \begin{enumerate}
  \item For $m = 1$ to $M$:\label{alg:loop}
  ...
 \end{enumerate}
\end{algorithm}
```

such that the "new" (`\ref{alg:loop}`) would be equal to current (`\ref{alg}.\ref{alg:loop}`)

Comment: Is this question still 'alive'? I wonder that `enumerate` is possible in an `algorithm` environment at all, since those `algorithm` - related environments are quite special in their LaTeX coding. Please post a compilable document, not just fragments